# Traveling from Denmark to USA - when to get Covid Test?

Tags: usa, air-travel, denmark, covid-19

I need to fly from Denmark to the USA. My flight is the 29 December at 09.00 am.

- Question 1: I’ve booked a PCR test the 27, but will first get the result at some point the 28th. I’ve read that my test results has to be less than 24 hours old, can I even use the PCR test then?
- Question 2: is the test results for boarding the airplane or at customs in the USA? (That will help answer questions 1)
- Question 3: Are both PCR and rapid test acceptable to get into the us? If so I wouldn’t need to take the PCR, and could just get a rapid the 28th at night.

Comment: As far as I know, it’s the time the test was taken which counts, not when you get the result.

Comment: That's a tough time frame to fly, post Christmas, morning departure, in a week when many things are closed :/

Comment: Are you flying direct to the US, or via say, Canada or UK or Spain?

Comment: Me fly direct to USA

Comment: As a last minute emergency alternative, you could fly to Mexico and then enter the US overland. No test required at all in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: all quotations taken from the [CDC FAQ](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html#general). Also, it matters when the test was taken, not when the result was delivered.

#### Question 1

The test has to be no more than 1 day old, not 24 hours:

> The 1-day period is 1 day before the flight’s departure. The Order uses a 1-day time frame instead of 24 hours to provide more flexibility to the air passenger and aircraft operator. By using a 1-day window, test acceptability does not depend on the time of the flight or the time of day that the test sample was taken.

### Question 2

I am not sure, when arriving in the USA they will probably check the test result as well but this is covered under question 1.

### Question 3

> You must be tested with a viral test to look for current infection – these include an antigen test or a nucleic acid amplification test (NAAT).

Rapid tests will suffice if they meet the requirements above:

> Rapid tests are acceptable if they are a viral test that meet the requirements under the Order.

Comment: Let's emphasise that the critical point is when the test was **taken**, not the result delivered. A test taken on the 27th is **not** valid for a flight on the 29th even if the result is delivered on the 28th. For a departure on the 29th (at any time), the test must be **taken** on the 28th.

Comment: @jcaron I made that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is information on the 1-day requirement from the CDC.

> The 1-day period is 1 day before the flight’s departure. The Order
> uses a 1-day time frame instead of 24 hours to provide more
> flexibility to the air passenger and aircraft operator. By using a
> 1-day window, test acceptability does not depend on the time of the
> flight or the time of day that the test sample was taken.
>
> For example, if your flight is at 1pm on a Friday, you could board
> with a negative test that was taken any time on the prior Thursday.

So it's relative to the day of departure.

Here's the current info from the CDC (Centers for Disease Control) for which tests are valid. Rapid tests are allowed but must meet certain criteria. Information is from [this website, "Requirement for Proof of Negative COVID-19 Test or Documentation of Recovery from COVID-19",](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html), accessed **20 December 2021** and excerpted below:

> **What types of SARS-CoV-2 tests are acceptable under the Order?**
>
> You must be tested with a viral test to look for current infection –
> these include an antigen test or a nucleic acid amplification test
> (NAAT).
>
> Phrases indicating a test is an antigen test could include, but not
> are not limited to:
>
> - Rapid antigen test
> - Viral antigen test
>
> Also, could be noted as
>
> - Antigen Chromatographic Digital Immunoassay,
> - Antigen Chemiluminescence Immunoassay, or
> - Antigen Lateral Flow Fluorescence
>
> Examples of available NAATs for SARS-CoV-2 include but are not restricted to:
>
> - Reverse transcription polymerase chain reaction (RT-PCR)
> - Isothermal amplification including:
>
>   - Nicking endonuclease amplification reaction (NEAR)
>   - Transcription mediated amplification (TMA)
>   - Loop-mediated isothermal amplification (LAMP)
>   - Helicase-dependent amplification (HDA)
>   - Clustered regularly interspaced short palindromic repeats (CRISPR)
>   - Strand displacement amplification (SDA)
>
> The test used must be
> authorized for use by the relevant national authority for the
> detection of SARS-CoV-2 in the country where the test is administered.
>
> A viral test conducted for U.S. Department of Defense (DOD) personnel,
> including DOD contractors, dependents, and other U.S. government
> employees, and tested by a DOD laboratory located in a foreign country
> also meets the requirements of the Order.

A more direct FAQ, **"Can I Get a Rapid Test?"**, has this answer:

> Rapid tests are acceptable if they are a viral test that meet the
> requirements under the Order.

Self-tests are allowed only if you have an associated tele-health appointment. The medical professional has to confirm that it's you, etc.

Comment: I’m not sure this answers the question about the time delay for the Covid test. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You're right. I didn't expressly answer your question. I was relying on the fact that certain rapid tests are approved, so you're likely better off just taking a rapid test. Looking farther, there is information about the 1 day requirement. I'll add it.

Comment: It seems like this answer is identical to mine and mine was complete first.

Comment: @Xnero I like how your answer is very focused, but for COVID-19 issues, I prefer to have as much information as possible like all the variation of names for tests that the CDC approves. Voters will decide.

Comment: @mkennedy If you are going to include test names that the CDC approves, *at least* format it as it is in the FAQ.

Comment: @Xnero Very good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get tested at Copenhagen airport directly before your flight see [Copenhagen Airport testing](https://www.cph.dk/en/practical/covid19/covid-19-testing-airport)

PCR tests take 4-6 hours to get results normally, and this is even more complicated over the Christmas period (see the link).  However Rapid Antigen tests are reported in 15-30 minutes, will be acceptable to US as they take place under the auspices of the testing company and provide an English certificate.

It is not immediately clear to me if you need to book this in advance or can just turn up, but of course you would want to leave extra time before your flight.